# Modify pandas iteration from iterrows to apply/vectorized format

Tags: python, pandas, performance

While using iterrows to implement the logic takes lot of time.Can some suggest a way on how I could optimize the code with vectorized/apply()

Below is the input table..From a partition of (ITEMSALE,ITEMID),I need to populate rows with rank=1 .If any column value is null in rank=1,I need to populate the next available value in that column.This has to be done for all columns in dataset.
[image]

Below is the output format expected

[image]

I have tried below logic using iterrows where am accessing values rowise.Performance is too low using this method.

[image]

Comment: Please provide text based data and code. Do not use images.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what  you need

```
df.loc[df.loc[df['Item_ID'].isna()].groupby('Item_Sale')['Date'].idxmin()]
```

Comment: Using groupby and first() helped to achieve the result.Thanks for helping out